# A book like Feynman's Lectures to Physics, which deals with Chemistry and provides insights

Tags: books

I have been reading The Feynman Lectures, and it provides a lot of basic knowledge in physics. I would like to know if there exists a book for chemistry like this too.

Comment: You might find this helpful: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/37303/resources-for-learning-chemistry

Answer (score 2):

About 20 years ago, I have got the German translation of ***Atoms, Electrons and Change* by Peter W. Atkins.** This short and simple book was inspired by the lectures on chemistry given by Michael Faraday (such as *The Chemical History of a Candle*).

Comment: Atkins does have several other chemistry books written for the layman as well. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter_Atkins#General_readers